# How can I reload a model on controller checkbox state change?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given some checkboxes that [`mut`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/mut?anchor=mut) a boolean, how can we automatically update the model using these booleans by querying the datastore in the route?

E.g.:

```js
model(params) {
  return this.store.query('email', {
    filter: {
      option1: controller.checkbox1, 
      option2: controller.checkbox2, 
      option3: controller.checkbox3
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two established patterns:

1. Using [query parameters](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/) for storing the filter values used in API query. Query params support reloading the model hook on changes out of the box.
2. A [`DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray), which `store.query()` resolves with, provides an `update()` method that will reload the query.

I would recommend query parameters in most cases as that also allows to share and bookmark the application state including the filters. It does not add a lot complexity if it's just about boolean values.

You could also the [`RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/RouterService/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo) to transition to the same route which works similar to refreshing the route. But it has some drawbacks as it adds more complexity compared to the other options and the default query parameters will be included in the route. See method documentation and the [RouterService RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0095-router-service.md) for more details on the last one.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. The feature from your first link that I was (and others are) looking for is `refreshModel: true`.

Answer (score -1):

You could move from `mut` to an action and use `this.refresh()`

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checkbox1 on-click=(action "refreshCheck")}}
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checkbox2 on-click=(action "refreshCheck")}}
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checkbox3 on-click=(action "refreshCheck")}}
```

```
actions: {
  refreshCheck(){
    this.refresh();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actions on controllers are (at least for that use case) a pattern that should be avoided. You could find more details in the discussion on the [Route actions RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/394). I would especially recommend the postings of Tom Dale, who speaks for the core team.

Comment: I hadn't seen that particular RFC.  Interesting discussion. The point of being consistent where you put actions is spot on. Controllers will be supported until they're depreciated.

Comment: There is a mistake in my first comment. I meant that action on routes should be avoided (except for the error and loading state actions). My hole point was that actions should be handled by components or controller but `refresh` method is only available on route.